# Append list item only to lists within selected tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I got a little [codepen](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/xgBeaJ) where I got multi selectable tabs (with jQuery selectable widget). Above that I got a form with a text input and a submit button. When I insert some text and submit it, it adds the text into the list on each tab. My goal is that the input text only get appended onto the lists of the selected tabs. 
Thats my javascript:

```
$(function() {
    function selectionChange(event, ui) {
        var items = $('.ui-selected', this).map(function () {
            return $(this).index();
        }).get();

        $("section").each(function () {
            $(this).toggle(items.indexOf($(this).index()) > -1);
        });
        console.log(items);
    }

    $("#selectable").selectable();
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: selectionChange,
        unselected: selectionChange
    });
});


$(function(){
   $('#plannerform').submit(function(e){
       var val = $(this).find('#plannername').val();
       $('ul.plannerlist').append('<li>' + val + '</li>');
       e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

And thats the HTML:

```
<form id="plannerform">
    <input id="plannername" placeholder="Name eingeben" type="text"></input><!--
    --><input id="plannersubmit" type="submit" value="eintragen"></input>
</form>

<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">FR PM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">SA AM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">SA PM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">SO AM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">SO PM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">MO AM</li>
</ol>

<div id="content">
  <section class="tabcontent">1
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">2
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>  
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">3
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">4
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">5
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>  
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">6
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul> 
  </section>
</div>
```

If you need more code, the full code is on my codepen which I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append to `$('.tabcontent:visible .plannerlist')` instead, and if none are visible (initial state), append to the one in the first `.tabcontent`

Here's a pen since the form submission won't work on SO http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/YNoNdN

```js
$(function() {
    // define one function, to be used for both select/unselect
    function selectionChange(event, ui) {
        // Get indexes of selected items in an array
        var items = $('.ui-selected', this).map(function () {
            return $(this).index();
        }).get();
        // Show or hide sections according to the corresponding option's selection
        $("section").each(function () {
            $(this).toggle(items.indexOf($(this).index()) > -1);
        });
        console.log(items);
    }

    $("#selectable").selectable();
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: selectionChange,
        unselected: selectionChange
    });
});


$(function(){
    $('#plannerform').submit(function(e){
        var val = $(this).find('#plannername').val();
        var $target = $('.tabcontent:visible').length ? $('.tabcontent:visible .plannerlist') : $('.tabcontent:first-child .plannerlist');
        $target.append('<li>' + val + '</li>');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
*{
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#selectable .ui-selecting { 
  background: #9eefbc;
  transition:.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s, background-color 0.8s;
 transition: transform 0.8s, background-color 0.8s;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-180deg);
 transform: perspective(300px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-180deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
 perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
}
#selectable .ui-selected { 
  background: #6dce91; 
  transition:all 0.8s;
}
#selectable { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  position:absolute;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left:20%;
  display:flex;
  transition:.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index:1;
  margin-top:3px;
}
#selectable li { 
  background:#ddffea;
  padding: 0.6em; 
  font-size: 1.4em; 
  flex-grow:1;
  transition:.3s ease-in-out;
  border:none;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:0.8em;
}

#selectable .ui-selected:after,
#selectable .ui-selected::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    margin-left:-50px;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity:1;
    animation:dreieckFade 1s forwards;
    border-top: solid 15px #6dce91;
    border-left: solid 20px transparent;
    border-right: solid 20px transparent;
}

@keyframes dreieckFade{
    0%{opacity:0;border-top: solid 0px #6dce91;}
    100%{opacity:1;border-top: solid 15px #6dce91;}
}

.ui-selectable-helper {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#content{
  width:60%;
  background-color:#9eefbc;
  margin-left:20%;
  padding-top:70px;
  margin-top:3px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}

.tabcontent{
    top:44px;
    background-color:transparent;
    z-index:0;
    transition:.3s ease-in-out;
    font-size:2em;
    display:none;
    padding-left:100px;
}

#plannername{
  width:40%;
  background-color:#9eefbc;
  margin-left:20%;
  border:0;
  font-size:2em;
  padding:20px;
}
#plannername:focus{
  outline:0;
}
#plannersubmit{
  width:20%;
  background-color:#6dce91;
  border:0;
  font-size:2em;
  padding:20px;
  transition:.2s ease-in-out;
}
#plannersubmit:hover{
  transition:.2s ease-in-out;
  padding-left:40px;
  cursor:pointer; 
}
#plannersubmit:focus{
  outline:0;
}
#plannersubmit:active{
  color:white;
}
.plannerlist{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form id="plannerform">
    <input id="plannername" placeholder="Name eingeben" type="text" autocomplete="off"></input><!--
    --><input id="plannersubmit" type="submit" value="eintragen"></input>
</form>
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">FR PM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">SA AM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">SA PM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">SO AM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">SO PM</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">MO AM</li>
</ol>
<div id="content">
  <section class="tabcontent">1
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">2
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>  
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">3
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">4
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">5
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>  
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">6
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul> 
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I didn't know that :visible. Thanks for that simple solution. That 2nd part, that the item gets appended onto the first list, when no tab is selected, is pretty irrelevant to me, because I want the user to first select some tabs and then submit (I'll identify that with some notes). But thanks for that :) Good to know.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus np. In that case you might disable the search input if someone hasn't selected a tab (probably a bad UX, since the user might not know they have to select a tab before searching), or make the first tab selected by default (seems like a better solution).

Comment: Yes, it's like a planner where you can sign up for some days. So I think disabling the search input is the best solution

Comment: Or better: I change the placeholder text to: "Please select tabs first" and disable it

Answer (score 0):

You could store the selected indices in the click handler, then filter those out when you append the data:

```
$(function() {
    //Create a variable to store the indices of selected items
    var selectedIndices = [];

    function selectionChange(event, ui) {
        var items = $('.ui-selected', this).map(function () {
            return $(this).index();
        }).get();

        $("section").each(function () {
            $(this).toggle(items.indexOf($(this).index()) > -1);
        });
        console.log(items);
        //Store the indices so that they can be accessed when the plannerform gets submitted
        selectedIndices = items;
    }

    $("#selectable").selectable();
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: selectionChange,
        unselected: selectionChange
    });

   $('#plannerform').submit(function(e){
       var val = $(this).find('#plannername').val();
       //filter the list, leaving only the elements whose indices are present in the selectedIndices array
       $('ul.plannerlist').filter(function(index) {
            return selectedIndices.indexOf(index) > -1;
        }).append('<li>' + val + '</li>');
       e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I guess adding :visible like this `$('.tabcontent:visible .plannerlist')` is alot easier. But I appreciate your help!